# i'm trying to plot antenna radiation in scilab

Tags: scilab

[formulla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sN4Z.png)

imp=377;

c=3*10^8;

f=3*10^6;

i0=1;

teta=0:0.01:2*%pi;

lam=c/f;

l=lam/2;

k=2*%pi/lam;

r=10*lam;

ete=%i*imp*i0*l*exp(-k*r)/(4*%pi*r).*sin(teta);

polarplot(teta,ete);
at line    56 of function polarplot ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.0\modules\graphics\macros\polarplot.sci line 69 )

min: Wrong type for input argument #1: A real matrix expected.

can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Did you try the given solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors given to `polarplot` have to be real. Maybe you are missing a call to `abs` to compute the modulus of `ete` :

```
polarplot(teta,abs(ete))
```

S.

Comment: Great, can you validate the answer then ?

Comment: i think it correct. because i ask other friend and the graph look similar

Comment: I mean, can you validate the answer in Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers